# PyQt4: how to add Hindi text to a QTextEdit

Tags: python, internationalization, pyqt4, qtextedit, hindi

How to add Hindi language support while writing text in pyqt?

Here is what I am getting.

[image: Python Console]

[image: PyQt4 Window]

Please tell me how I can write Hindi language in a PyQt4 window.

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear, and should be re-opened. The OP is simply asking why Hindi text is not displayed properly in a `QTextdit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black boxes can mean two things:

1. The font in the text editor doesn't contain the necessary characters.
2. You made a mistake when converting the text to a Unicode string.

Next steps:

1. Try to copy&paste the text from the console to the editor. If it doesn't, you need a different font. See `QtGui.QFont()`.
2. If copy&paste works, then you made a mistake when preparing the text. Show us the code if you need further help.

Comment: It's obviously the font. The OP most likely pasted the same text that is shown correctly in the python console (see the screenshots in the question).